# Encode contents between Two Special Strings

Tags: php, preg-match, preg-match-all

All I want is to Get contents between two strings like the following line:

```
$content = '81Lhello82R 81Lmy82R 81Lwife82R';
```

I wish to get all contents between `81L` and `82R`, then encode them to Base64 automatically by Preg_match I think, I've done some ways to do it but didn't get what was expected!

Base Form:

```
81Lhello82R 81Lmy82R 81Lwife82R
```

Output:

```
81LaGVsbG8=82R 81LbXk=82R 81Ld2lmZQ==82R
```

Comment: What string you expeted? "hello my wife" or "hellomywife"?

Comment: @GardenApple no, Look at the example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard rules:

```
$leftMask = '81L';
$rightMask = '82R';
$content = '81Lhello82R 81Lmy82R 81Lwife82R';
preg_match_all('#'.$leftMask.'(.*)'.$rightMask.'#U',$content, $out);
$output = [];
foreach($out[1] as $val){
   $output[] = $leftMask.base64_encode($val).$rightMask;
}
$result = str_replace($out[0], $output, $content);
```

RegExp rules

```
$leftMask = '\d{2}L';
$rightMask = '\d{2}R';
$content = '81Lhello82R 81Lmy82R 81Lwife82R';
preg_match_all('#('.$leftMask.')(.*)('.$rightMask.')#U',$content, $out);;
$output = [];
foreach($out[2] as $key=>$val){
   $output[] = $out[1][$key].base64_encode($val).$out[3][$key];
}
$result = str_replace($out[0], $output, $content);
```

Comment: is there a way to get 81L and 82R too? without adding them manually? cuz there will be a lot of strings such as 88L , 89R...

Comment: You wanted add manually rules or have universal rules? For example content between \d{2}L and  \d{2}R

Comment: Yeah, Universal Rules.

Answer (score 0):

This is a job for [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php):

```
$content = '81Lhello82R 81Lmy82R 81Lwife82R';
$output = preg_replace_callback(
            '/(?<=\b\d\dL)(.+?)(?=\d\dR)/',
            function($matches) {
                return base64_encode($matches[1]);  // encode the word and return it
            },
            $content);
echo $output,"\n";
```

Where

- `(?<=\b\d\dL)` is a positive [lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) that makes sure we have 2 digits and the letter L before the word to encode
- `(?=\d\dR)` is a positive [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) that makes sure we have 2 digits and the letter R after the word to encode
- `(.+?)` is the capture group that contains the word to encode

**Output:**

```
81LaGVsbG8=82R 81LbXk=82R 81Ld2lmZQ==82R
```